# Gitea offers wrong SSH key

Tags: ssh, deployment, git, gitea

I'm running Gitea on a virtual machine that is publicly accessible under `gitea.myorg.foo`. Here's the server part relevant to my SSH configuration of my configuration file:

```
[server]                                                                                                                       
SSH_DOMAIN       = gitea.myorg.foo                                                                                            
DOMAIN           = gitea.myorg.foo                                                                                            
ROOT_URL         = https://gitea.myorg.foo/                                                                                   
DISABLE_SSH      = false                                                                                                       
SSH_PORT         = 22                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
OFFLINE_MODE     = false
```

This means that I'm running the server's sshd, not Gitea's internal sshd.

The server runs under a user called `git`. In `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`, the authorized keys (per user and deployment keys) are listed.

Unfortunately, the deployment key is not offered when I try to clone a repository with that deployment key enabled.

Let's say I'd like to clone `git@gitea.myorg.foo/org/repo.git`, I get offered a key with a totally different signature than what is displayed under "Deploy Keys" in the web UI. When I run `ssh-keyscan gitea.myorg.foo`, I only get signatures **not** to be found in `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

How can I figure out and configure what keys SSH is offering to the client?

Edit: I noticed that the key offered is the one marked as `HostKey` defined in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Do I need to use Gitea's internal SSH server, or could I configure my native SSH server accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mixed up the host key and my deployment key. It's totally OK that the host key is returned. However, I made the mistake to rely on the deployment key in the `.knwon_hosts` file, where I should use the host key instead.